# Tensorflow: Replace one op with another(maybe even 2 ops)

Tags: tensorflow, graph, replace, editor

My goal is to build a script to change an operation into another one using TF's graph editor. So far I tried making a script that just changes the input kernel weights of a Conv2D, but to no avail, as the interface is pretty confusing.

```
with tf.Session() as sess:

    model_filename = sys.argv[1]

    with gfile.FastGFile(model_filename, 'r') as f:

        graph_def = graph_pb2.GraphDef()
        text_format.Merge(f.read(), graph_def)
        importer.import_graph_def(graph_def)

        #my_sgv = ge.sgv("Conv2D", graph=tf.get_default_graph())
        #print my_sgv

        convs = find_conv2d_ops(tf.get_default_graph())
        print convs

        my_sgv = ge.sgv(convs)
        print my_sgv

        conv_tensor = tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name(convs[0].name + ':0')
        conv_weights_input = tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name(convs[0].inputs[1].name)

        weights_new = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([1, 1, 1, 8], stddev=0.03),
                                  name='Wnew')

        ge.graph_replace(conv_tensor, {conv_weights_input: weights_new})
```

The error is "input needs to be a Tensor: ". Can someone please provide some insights?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are dealing with a `tf.Variable` you don't need to use graph editor. [`tf.assign`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/assign) will be sufficient.

You can use it like the following:

```
assign_op = tf.assign(conv_weights_input, weights_new)
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(assign_op)
```

If you are looking to sub out operations and not weights. Consider the following example (modified from [this](https://gist.github.com/ByungSunBae/393071e46409737cd341360a69957906) example):

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.contrib.graph_editor as ge

def build():
    a_pl = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, name="a")
    b_pl = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, name="b")
    c = tf.add(a_pl, b_pl, name="c")

build() #or load graph from disc

a = tf.constant(1.0, shape=[2, 3], name="a_const")
b = tf.constant(2.0, shape=[2, 3], name="b_const")

a_pl = tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name("a:0")
b_pl = tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name("b:0")
c = tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name("c:0")

c_ = ge.graph_replace(c, {a_pl: a, b_pl: b})

with tf.Session() as sess:
    #no need for placeholders
    print(sess.run(c_))
    #will give error since a_pl and b_pl have no value
    print(sess.run(c))
```

The issue with your code is that you're dealing with wights, and not tensors. The crux of the above example is that the first argument is the target tensor (output tensor) that have the to be replaced tensors as dependencies. The second argument are the actual tensors you want to replace.

It's also worth noting that `conv_weights_input` is actually a tensor, where `weights_new` is a `tf.Variable`. I believe what you want is to replace `weights_new` with a new conv operation with random weight initialisation.

Comment: Thanks! But what if I want to insert other operation at the output of Conv2D? Or, as a start, replace Conv2D with another operation?